# PHP PDO with Minus sign in query filter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP search that is giving me issues:

```
$filter = "123-N";                    
$qry = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = :MyField LIMIT 1  ");
$qry->bindParam(':MyField', $filter);
$qry->execute();
$result = $qry->fetch();
```

It is giving me this error:

> Failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'N' in
> 'where clause'

The same search in MySQL workbench works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = "123-N" LIMIT 1 ;
```

I have tried to encapsulate it, or write it in its own query and not bind it, but nothing seems to help.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Double-check that the error is coming from this code, and not some different code where you are interpolating the variable directly into the query string. There is no way a bound parameter can cause the error you show, but if you did but the variable in the SQL string, it would.

Comment: What is the error message in full please, including the `.php` file and line number

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, between your comment and nbk that got it for me.  thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no way that the accepted answer is relevant to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$filter = "'123-N'";
```

OR

```
$filter = "123-N"; 
...
$qry = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = QUOTE(:MyField) LIMIT 1  ");
```

Both get you the same result and mysql recognizes a string

The basic problem is that MySQL tries to interpret the value and needs a hint